# Several regressions between a comon x and different yi for each level of a categorical variable

Tags: r

How I can modify the below code, or suggest a better solution, to calculate the regression line between x and each of yi i=1 to n (suppose n equals to 3) separately for each level of B and bring all the results (intercepts, coefficients,R values) into a new data.frame. I mean a data set which the first column refers to levels of B and the other column are the value of the coefficient, r.square for each `x` and `yi`.

```
vars <- names(a[,grepl("y",names(a))])
fits <- lapply(vars, function(x) {lm(substitute(i ~ x, list(i = as.name(x))), data = a)})
summary <-lapply(fits,summary)

subject<-seq(1,20,1)
x<-seq(10,29,1)
B<-rep(1:2,10)
y1<-seq(15,34,1)
y2<-seq(20,39,1)
y3<-seq(50,69,1)
a<-data.frame(subject,x,B,y1,y2,y3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

a %>% gather(key = variable, value = value, -subject, -x, -B) %>%
  filter(B == as.numeric(gsub("y", "", variable))) %>% 
  group_by(B, variable) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(models = data %>% map(., ~lm(value~x, data = .))
         ,results = models %>% map(., tidy)
         ,r.squared = models %>% map(., ~glance(.) %>% select(r.squared))) %>% 
  unnest(r.squared) %>% 
  unnest(results)
```

## results

```
# A tibble: 4 × 8
      B variable r.squared        term estimate    std.error    statistic       p.value
  <int>    <chr>     <dbl>       <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1       y1         1 (Intercept)        5 3.520120e-15 1.420406e+15 6.759543e-119
2     1       y1         1           x        1 1.773411e-16 5.638852e+15 1.095702e-123
3     2       y2         1 (Intercept)       10 6.950480e-15 1.438749e+15 6.100095e-119
4     2       y2         1           x        1 3.340188e-16 2.993844e+15 1.735342e-121
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. May I know that why your code's results is different from mtoto's results (the solution below)?

Comment: I made a different interpretation of the question. It states _...regression line between x and each of yi i=1 to n (suppose n equals to 3) separately for each level of B_.

Comment: thanks for your help. Just two questions. 1-How can I have also the value of r-square of each regression. 2-(I can make a new question if you think it is too much to answer) How can I modify your code to have regressions between x and yi for the level of B with the same index, I mean lm(y1~x when B==1), lm(y2~x when B==2). I need to  make a subset of results when B and variable have the same index, for example, B=1 and  y1, B=2 and  y2 (I need a loop function since in my real dataset I have n value for B and y)

Comment: 1. I added a step to fetch r-squared. 2. I added a step to only keep cases where B is equal to the index of y according to wish in your comment. This setup should generalise to a setup with n y-variables.

Answer (score 1):

You are better off tidying your data first using `gather()`, so all the columns starting with `"y"` are in one variable. Consequently we nest your data using the latter as a `key`, and apply the `lm` fit per group using `map()` from `purrr` package. Finally we use `tidy()` from `broom` package to clean up the output and return it as a `data.frame`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

a %>% gather(key,value,-subject,-x,-B) %>%
        nest(-key) %>% 
        mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(value ~ x, data = .)),
               tidied = map(model, tidy)) %>%
        unnest(tidied)
#    key        term estimate    std.error    statistic       p.value
#  <chr>       <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#1    y1 (Intercept)        5 2.838021e-15 1.761791e+15 1.375776e-264
#2    y1           x        1 1.395654e-16 7.165099e+15 1.485006e-275
#3    y2 (Intercept)       10 2.838021e-15 3.523582e+15 5.248168e-270
#4    y2           x        1 1.395654e-16 7.165099e+15 1.485006e-275
#5    y3 (Intercept)       40 2.063483e-16 1.938470e+17 2.462998e-301
#6    y3           x        1 1.014760e-17 9.854551e+16 4.789215e-296
```

Comment: thanks for your help. May I know that why your code's result is different from JohanSjoberg's solution.

Comment: because he's grouping by both `B` and `variable`, if you add `nest(-key,-B)` you get same result, however it wasn't entirely clear which one is your expected output.